# Angular component not showing when set to true

Tags: html, angular, sass, angular-components

To put it short, I have a site where when you do a certain action like clicking a button you get a specific result (on or off). When the result is on, a component modal is supposed to show but I don't see it (it's supposed to look like a new window on the page but not really a window). If I inspect the DOM I see it there with a size of 0x0 which doesn't make sense. Everything logically seems to be working I can't figure out why I can't get this to display. Any insight is appreciated.

The modal html looks like this (results is just pushed to when clicked so Attempt can be 5 lines and i can confirm in console with logging that it is pushing and working as expected):

```
<div class="modal">
    <h2>Results</h2>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let result of results; let i = index">
        <p>
            Attempt {{ i + 1 }}
        </p>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Styling looks like this:

```
.modal-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.modal {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

On the homePage component I have a div that looks like this. The showModal variable is set to true when the result is 'on':

```
 <div *ngIf="result === 'on'>
    <div *ngIf="showModal" class="modal-overlay">
      <app-results-modal [results]="results"></app-results-modal>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Styling for home looks like:

```
.on-container {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.on {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.input-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.on-info {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
```

Entire lading page html with the modal code above:

```
<ng-container>
  <div *ngIf="quote">
    <h1>Click a button</h1>
    <blockquote>
      "Can you click it"
    </blockquote>
    <button (click)="pushClickOn()">Click</button>
    <button (click)="pushClickOff()">ClickOff</button>

    <div *ngIf="result !== ''">
      <p>{{ resultMessage }}</p>
      <div *ngIf="result !== 'on'">
        <h3>Hints:</h3>
        <ul *ngIf="hints.length > 0">
          <li *ngFor="let hint of hints">{{ hint }}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="result === 'off'">
        <p>Currently off</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="result === 'on'">
    <div *ngIf="showModal" class="modal-overlay">
      <app-results-modal [results]="results"></app-results-modal>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

I did some logging to see what the current result of the click was.
When I clicked Off, result was off. showModal was false.
When I clicked On, result was on and showModal was true and at this point I would expect to see the results modal show up but it didn't.

Comment: You're missing a closing double quote `"result === 'on'>`

Comment: @Phix copy/paste error onto here but dang wish that was it

Comment: Show your controller code, there are 2 ngIfs around the modal component, are you sure those are both set to true?

Comment: Sure, 

pushClickOn(){this.showModal = true; this.result = 'on'}
pushClickOff(){this.showModal = false; this.result = 'off'}

Comment: Dunno, the 2 nested ngIf throw some code smell but if you're sure they are both true I'd try to set up a repro on stackblitz and edit your post with that.

Answer (score 0):

So my issue was that i was importing bootstrap styles in the root styles.scss file and that was making all the styles jacked. removed it and works as expected.